# Getting table header info on $connection->selectall_array($command)

Tags: mysql, perl

I am using `$connection->selectall_array($command)` to grab data from MySQL. I am curious if there is a different command where my return is the same, except the first element will be the data column's name?

Obviously I know them already.  But would be convenient if there was a way.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `->selectall_array` then. If you prepare and execute a statement handle, you get the information from `@{$sth->{NAME_lc}}`. Alternatively, fetch the rows as hashrefs, then you implicitly get the header information.

Comment: If you pass `{Slice => {}}` as the second argument to `selectall_array` or `selectall_arrayref`, it will return hashrefs instead of arrayrefs, where the keys are the column name; this would be the simplest way to get that information, but the structure would be different.